# Force Powershell to ask for Creds

Tags: powershell

Hoping someone can assist me... Is there a way to force powershell to prompt for Credentials before then loading another script?

I have a gui which is a series of buttons which will load various other scripts. However one or two of them require authentication with another account. So i want the button to be hit it asks for creds then runs that PS.1 file as that account.

Most i have just coded like below so it loads the script.

```
$Script1.Add_Click({
          & 'Location of File'
})
```

Thanks

Comment: Add `$cred = Get-Credential` as the first command inside the `Add_Click` event handler scriptblock.

Comment: Perfect. I was expecting it to be a little more long winded for that. Works a treat. Thank you @Theo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Theo said solved this:

Add `$cred = Get-Credential` as the first command inside the `Add_Click` event handler scriptblock.